# How to disable the gridview rows border

Tags: asp.net

Can we disable the gridview horizontal line ? I want to display grid without horizontal lines
help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView renders as a table so wrap your GridView in a `<div>` with a class that sets the border of all contained `<td>` to 0

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Try using FireBug or IE developer toolbar to make sure you are selecting the correct class for you TDs. Kindness

Answer (score 104):

Set `GridLines="None"` on your `GridView`

Comment: I don't know if this was what Surya sasidhar was asking but it helped me. This removes all grid lines from the GridView (wich is what I wanted).

Comment: This can be an answer too. Helped me too.

Comment: This is answer is Microsoft best practice see grid view documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 9):

Setting both:

```
BorderStyle="None"
```

and

```
GridLines="None"
```

on your Gridview will remove all of the lines.

Answer (score 5):

use this code for your GridView to disable lines

```
  GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
BorderWidth="0px"
```

Comment: That only seems to work for the outside of the table. Using Gridlines="None" does the trick for the inner cells.